# Django- cannot import ReCaptchaField from captcha.fields

Tags: python, django, recaptcha, captcha

I am trying to import ReCaptchaField from captcha.fields. However I am getting this error-

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ReCaptchaField' from 'captcha.fields'
```

Comment: There's no `ReCaptchaField` in [the docs](https://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) - shouldn't it be `CaptchaField` instead? Also, please, provide links to github/pypi of exotic packages you use (or `pip install` command at least).

Comment: I've already done the pip install captcha, pip install recaptcha and pip install django-simple-captcha.

Comment: Well. When you `import` from `captcha`, you're using `django-simple-captcha`. There's no `ReCaptchaField` in it. Please don't `pip install recaptcha`: it's 10 years old and not maintained.

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Same here, I have no clue how some wrong version of `django-recaptcha` was installed.

`conda list` showed me the below and I thought I am indeed using the latest version, but when I compared the source file of `fields.py` (located in your_env\Lib\site-packages\captcha, I noticed I was using some other version:

`django-recaptcha          3.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi`

I uninstalled and reinstalled and that solved my problem.

```
pip uninstall django-recaptcha    
pip install django-recaptcha --no-cache-dir`
```

Answer (score 1):

django-recaptcha version < 4

```
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
```

django-recaptcha version >= 4

```
from django_recaptcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
```

See details here: https://github.com/django-recaptcha/django-recaptcha/releases/tag/4.0.0

> Package namespace renamed! The package namespace captcha has been
> renamed to django_recaptcha to avoid conflicts with other captcha
> packages.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. On windows there's no CaptchaField but ReCaptchaField but when I deploy my app (GAE for example), I got the same error. And the solution is have an exception handler:

```
try: 
  from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField
except ImportError:
  from captcha.fields import CaptchaField
```